# Set the current birthday from data in CakePHP

Tags: forms, default-value, cakephp-2.1

I'm using this way to set the birthday in CakePHP, but when i turn back in the page I always get the current day date, so if I save the page without touch it, i get the today date as birthday:

```
<?php
$attributes = array (
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 100,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0,
    'label'=> false,
    'default' => $user['Profile']['birthday'],
    'value'=>$user['Profile']['birthday'] // how to set the previous saved data?
);
$options = array (
    'id' => 'birthday',
    'after' => '<div class="message">Inserisce la tua data di nascita</div>'
);
echo $this->Form->input('Profile.birthday', $attributes, $options);
?>
```

How can i set the previous saved data from the database to the form?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that you are writing some kind of Edit-Form. In this case, CakePHP should automagically set the saved form data in your inputs. You should be able to savely discard `default` and `value` in your `$options`-array.

Debug `$this->form->data` to see whether the data is there. Otherwise you should check your controller code.

By the way: the signature of the input function is [`public function input($fieldName, $options = array())`](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/form-helper#line-942), so you probably want to merge the values in your `$options`-array to your `$attributes`-array.

Answer (score 0):

This type of input stores data in this format:

your can put the value in controller this format:

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['birthday']['year'] ='xxxx'; 
$this->request->data['Profile']['birthday']['month']='xx';
$this->request->data['Profile']['birthday']['day'] = 'xx';
```

It will automatically display as selected in view.

Ask if not work for you